# Python CPU Clock. time.clock() vs time.perf_counter() vs time.process_time()

Tags: python, time, clock

I wanted to measure how long sections of my code run. I needed this to be deterministic so that I get the same duration every time (seconds/milliseconds/etc) regardless of what is happening in the background. So i wanted to measure CPU time using time.clock() on unix.

time.clock() has since been decrecated and its suggested to switch to either perf_counter or process_time. I was looking at the python doc and found the following.

> time.perf_counter() → float Return the value (in fractional seconds)
> of a performance counter, i.e. a clock with the highest available
> resolution to measure a short duration. It does include time elapsed
> during sleep and is system-wide. The reference point of the returned
> value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of
> consecutive calls is valid.
>
> time.process_time() → float Return the value (in fractional seconds)
> of the sum of the system and user CPU time of the current process. It
> does not include time elapsed during sleep. It is process-wide by
> definition. The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so
> that only the difference between the results of consecutive calls is
> valid.

Since I am not using any form of sleep in my code, the primary difference seems to be 'process-wide' and 'system-wide'. Could sometime elaborate the difference?

Secondly, is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: Process time is the amount of time your code ran. System time is the amount of time that was spent running system (i.e. not your) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both perf_counter and timeit will give you the time that your block of code tested had taken to perform.

time.process_time() it does not and it calculates what the CPU have taken, which is not necessarily the same as the function or block of code.

I found this thread on [Github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/17316), seems that the question is quite advanced and may be completely different depending on the OS or program to be benchmark-ed.

> Something that time.process_time() is not counting is the Parent Multi-thread:

"One consequence of using time.process_time is that the time spent in child processes of the benchmark is not included. Multithreaded benchmarks also return the total CPU time counting all CPUs."

### perf_counter

```
from time import perf_counter


start = perf_counter()

for _ in range(10000):
    x = "-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))
end = perf_counter()
print('Perf Counter= ', end-start)
# Perf Counter=  0.23170840000000004
```

---

### timeit

```
import timeit

print(timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))', number=10000))
# 0.20687929999999993
```

Comment: I have read in a couple of resources that accessing CPU time on windows is not possible/hard and is much easier on unix. Since, I am using a unix system I feel this should not be a problem.

That said, if I were to measure the CPU and I ran the same code 10 times, I would expect to get the same CPU time which I do not get if I re-run the same code multiple time. Any solution/fix to that?

Comment: I don't understand you question. You mean that if you run some test on the same code, and each test loops through the code about 10 times, you always get a different timing? If is this what you mean I don't see the problem (unless is a considerable amount of time) and not something that has to be 'fixed,' you will always get a slightly different result on each test.